# Regex : only string can be accepted nothing else ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working on `ruby on rails` here is the code for `regex`

```
string_regex = /[a-z]+\z/i
validates :name , :format => { :with => string_regex , :message => "should not contain special character" }
```

**`Attempts`**:

1. dbcda-> true
2. abjdkbcak-> true
3. jgh1213 -> false
4. 1314134@#$ -> false
5. jbh31$ -> false
6. `,,,,,,,` -> `false`
7. `kjgh,g,,` -> **`TRUE`**(Which should be false).

Comment: Consider using beginning/end meta-chars.

Comment: I don't see how `kjgh,g,,` could be true since there is a `\z` anchor (absolute end of string).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `/\A[a-z]+\z/i` since you don't want any special characters from the beginning of your string (^) to the end of it (\z)

For help, try http://rubular.com/

[Edit] Changed as mentioned by @2called-chaos

Comment: Actually, to be really correct you would need to delimit with `\A` and `\z`. `^` is start of line, `\A` is start of string.

Comment: Hum, you're right... or the it should be /^[a-z]+$/i... for the whole line... Ok, edit. Thanks!